# Get current VisualForce page name from detail page

Tags: visualforce

I need to work on a button in a record detail page. I can't find the page to look at in the dev console. None of the usual suspects seem to be the right page. It is the detail page of a custom object. How can I find the exact vf page name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it from View action under `Buttons, Links, and Actions` section in the Custom object.

Clicking on `View` link it will be landed to following page and you can find visualforce page name.

[image]